# How to store generated number using loop in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I was trying to use for loop for generating values from a dataset and store it into another different dataframe. But I could not find any way out of this. For example consider the code below:

```
for(i in 1:20){
    print(i)
}
```

This code will give the number between 1 to 20 separately. I need these values to be stored in a new data frame. I tried some approaches like declaring a data frame and a few others, but I am facing different errors.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: `my_df <- data.frame(a = 1:20)` — try to avoid for loops for basic functionality like this.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use loops to generate this sequence of numbers

Comment: @Richard Thanks. This works well. I tried the suggestion from the comment below and got a good result.

Comment: @Paul, yes I do not need always but I'm running some more complex analysis where the built-in functions not generating appropriate results. Using indexing as we do in MATLAB or other languages did not work in R. But I needed this to be done to get the desired outcome. Thanks, everyone for your time and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This can be done to achieve the set aim, but is a very bad habit in R, please never grow a vector

You ca do

```
> newdf <- as.data.frame(c())
> 
> for (i in 1:20){   
        newdf <- rbind(newdf,i)
       }
```

which just puts row for row `i` underneath the "before coming" `i`

you can do this colum wise by changing `rbind` to `cbind`